# Where are login messages logged?

Tags: ubuntu

I suspect there is an error in my `.profile` configuration file. In order to find it I would like to have a look at the file where login errors are logged. I see nothing in `/var/log/syslog`. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system only records autorization attempts not what happens afterwards. If you think your .profile is broken is then you'll need to add your own instrumentation.